# Auto Loop (Export) in R

Tags: r, for-loop, forecasting

I am importing historical data from a CSV file with two columns (datestamp and values), do forecast in R, and have the forecast values exported back to CSV. All fine and dandy except that I am forecasting many different types of historical data, each with their own CSV file. I want to be able to create a for-loop to read all the CSV historical files from one folder, make forecasts, and stash it and export the forecast values to CSV on a separate folder.

This is the code I am using:

```
df <- read.csv("C:/.../sample3.csv")
m <- prophet(df)
future <- make_future_dataframe(m, periods = 365)
forecast <- predict(m, future)
write.csv(forecast, 'C:/.../testoutput2.csv')
```

I am new to R and I have been checking resources online but hasn't found any solution. Hope someone can help me here. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that you want to loop over the files in a folder. Use `list.files` to get a list of all the CSV files and then you can loop. The output files will be of the format *out_filename.csv*

```
setwd("c:/something/something/")
for (file in list.files(pattern ="*.csv")){

  df <- read.csv(file)
  m <- prophet(df)
  future <- make_future_dataframe(m, periods = 365)
  forecast <- predict(m, future)
  write.csv(forecast, sprintf("out_%s.csv", file)

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked perfectly!